# How to build a query with MongoDB C# Driver v2?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I'm trying to build a query in multiple steps but it looks like fluent interface(LINQ methods defined on IQueryable) is gone in the new version of C# driver.

```
//get the collection
IMongoCollection<WorkerSession> workerSessions = Select<WorkerSession>();

if (query.IsOngoing.HasValue)
{

    IFindFluent<WorkerSession, WorkerSession> items = query.IsOngoing.Value 
                        ? workerSessions.Find(session => session.CompletedOn == null)
                        : workerSessions.Find(session => session.CompletedOn != null);

}
```

I want to keep adding filters but IFindFluent interface doesn't seem to support that. Depending on the parameters, I may not even have a filter. How do I build the query in multiple steps?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm using v2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this there is a class for building filters. You are supposed to call Find method once when you constructed the full filter.

```
var filterBuilder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<WorkerSession>();
var filter = filterBuilder.Empty;

if (query.IsOngoing.HasValue)
{
    filter = filterBuilder.And(query.IsOngoing.Value
        ? new ExpressionFilterDefinition<WorkerSession>(session => session.CompletedOn == null)
        : new ExpressionFilterDefinition<WorkerSession>(session => session.CompletedOn != null));
}

var filtered = await workerSessions.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Please post your answer if you know an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB query filtering using [Slazure](http://www.slazure.com/)'s Linq provider makes your scenario a lot simpler. Here is a Slazure example where a fictitious "TestCustomers" collection is queried for all customers that are younger than 22 yo and have signed up for the newsletter, finally the customer document's email property is written to the console:

```
using SysSurge.Slazure.AzureDocumentDB.Linq;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core.Linq.QueryParser;

public void ShowYoungCustomerWithNewsletterEmails()
{
    // Get a reference to the collection
    dynamic storage = new QueryableStorage<DynDocument>("URL=https://contoso.documents.azure.com:443/;DBID=DDBExample;TOKEN=VZ+qKPAkl9TtX==");
    QueryableCollection<DynDocument> collection = storage.TestCustomers;

    // Build collection query
    var queryResult = collection.Where("SignedUpForNewsletter = true and Age < 22");

    foreach (var document in queryResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(document.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IMongoCollection to get your collection and then use AsQueryable

Example:

```
    var query = collection.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Name))
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(entity.Name));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Description))
        query = query.Where(p => p.Description.Contains(entity.Description));

    var YourList=query.ToList();
```